# How to write non-serialized objects, such as Shapes, in a file so they can then be read later

Tags: java, serialization, javafx, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a program with a class similar to the basic example below:

```
public class Vertex extends Circle implements Serializable {
    private int vertexID;
    private final static double SIZE = 10.0;

    // Constructor
    public Vertex(int ID, double x, double y) {
        super(x, y, SIZE, Color.BLUE);
        this.vertexID = ID;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is write a `List<Vertex> myVertices` to a file using the `ObjectOutputStream`, which requires that each class implements the `Serializable` interface. An example is shown below:

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
File fileChosen = fc.showOpenDialog(window);

try {               
   FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileChosen);
   ObjectOutputStream oOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fOutStream);

   oOutStream.writeObject(myVertices);
   oOutStream.close();
} catch {
    // Exception handling here
}
```

The problem with the implementation above is that, although `Vertex` implements `Serializable`, the super class `Circle` and its super class `Shape` do not implement `Serializable`. The result is that the file contains the `Vertex` objects but all `Shape` details are lost and default to 0.

Is there a simple solution to this sort of problem? My only current option seems to be to create my own `Shape`/`Circle` that stores the location/display data as doubles so that it can then be `Serializable`. Obviously for one class this isn't too much effort, but I have a few other `Shape` objects I'd like to save as well. I would, I assume, then have to either construct actual `Shape` objects to display them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a writeObject/readObject method which saves the additional state that you need.

[Serialization - readObject writeObject overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963445/serialization-readobject-writeobject-overides)

[Uses of readObject/writeObject in Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911833/uses-of-readobject-writeobject-in-serialization)

[Why are readObject and writeObject private, and why would I write transient variables explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467313/why-are-readobject-and-writeobject-private-and-why-would-i-write-transient-vari)

[Java Custom Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization)

[Java: efficiency of writeObject vs writeExternal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443951/java-efficiency-of-writeobject-vs-writeexternal)

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody wants to see the actual code for a `Shape`, specifically `Circle` object, here is what I implemented thanks to the accepted answer. Also included an example of a `List<Vertex> myVertices = new ArrayList()`:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
    oos.writeInt(vertexID);
    oos.writeObject(myVertices);
    oos.writeDouble(super.getCenterX());
    oos.writeDouble(super.getCenterY());
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Read in same order as write
    this.vertexID = ois.readInt();
    this.myVertices = (List<Vertex>) ois.readObject();
    super.setCenterX(ois.readDouble());
    super.setCenterY(ois.readDouble());

    // Default Circle properties
    super.setRadius(SIZE); // Default
    super.setFill(Color.BLUE); // Default
}
```