# do we have to call parent class's readObject() method while using custom serialization in java?

Tags: java, serialization

i was referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443951/java-efficiency-of-writeobject-vs-writeexternal) it mentions that

> when a Serializable class implementing readObject/writeObject is subclassed, and if the subclass has its own readObject/writeObject, they don't need to call super's readObject/writeObject. Not so if the super/subclass instead implement Externalizable. In this case, super's writeExternal/readExternal need to be explicitly called. However, this difference is irrelevant from an efficiency point of view.

1. is this true?
2. how do i understand this ?
3. does this mean for every read/write Object method the compiler adds
   a call to default**read/write**Object() method in first line?
4. how does deserialization would behave for custom read methods , how
   does its gonna resolve parent class objects without superclass
   constructor example: *i only write child class object in stream , and during deseralization what values will i see for parent class objects*?
5. or it just behaves like writeExternal/readExternal methods ?